# What is the difference between Axios and SuperAgent libraries?

Tags: javascript, axios, superagent

I am learning JavaScript and I can see, in multiple big projects, SuperAgent is being used for HTTP Request. I am using Axios for learning purpose, but wondering what makes SuperAgent different to Axios?

Comment: See also:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40029787/axios-vs-superagent

Comment: Thank you @brad, but it's only answered in specific context, doesn't seem to cover all aspects.

Comment: There's an answer there that talks about a promise API vs. callback.  Your question is very general... did you have any specific questions?

Comment: Thank you. @Brad I am just looking to get brief overview of both libraries so I could know which one I should use going forward.

Comment: Experiment with both, use whatever works best for your use.  Both are using the same underlying Node.js libraries.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

axios has more stars than superagent, [check here](https://www.npmtrends.com/axios-vs-request-promise-vs-superagent)

If you are doing front end, axios is probably more popular, e.g. vue uses [axios](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html), I am doing back end, either one works.

But just like one answer in [Axios vs Superagent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40029787/axios-vs-superagent) said "I’d base my decision on other factors, like which API you like better, and library size " I tried both and finally chose **supergent** b/c superagent has [build-in retry](https://ladjs.github.io/superagent/#retrying-requests)

axios does not provide retry, https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/164. I really don't like the idea of introducing another module just for retry, not to mention there are already 2 different modules now, `axios-retry` vs `retry-axios`.

Besides, thru my limited test, this issue https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/553 has not been fully fixed.

Comment: At the time I am writing this neither axios-retry or retry-axios work with axios 0.19.0 (released 4 months ago)

1. https://github.com/softonic/axios-retry/issues/94

2. https://github.com/JustinBeckwith/retry-axios/issues/62

Comment: As in 2023 there is another library called [alova](https://alova.js.org/), which specifically **aims** to compete with axios, and alova also provides [retry](https://alova.js.org/strategy/sensorless-data-interaction/request-retry/)

Answer (score 15):

`superagent` and `axios` are HTTP client libraries. They are both very mature and picking between the two ultimately comes down to preference. Here's what it looks like to make a `POST` request with a JSON body using each library:

```
// superagent
await request
  .post('/to/my/api') // URI
  .set('Authorization', authorizationKey) // Header
  .send({ foo: 'bar' })  // Body
  // then creates a promise that returns the response
  .then(res => res.body)
```

---

```
/* axios */
// axios exclusively returns promises
// URI, body, request options are provided in one call
await request.post('/to/my/api', { 
  foo: 'bar'
}, {
  headers: {
    Authorization: authorizationKey
  }
})
```